# bash script to parse a specific record number and field from a text file?

Tags: parsing, bash, field

Assuming mpstat-log.txt file below, how can I parse the results of a file and get the %idle field for the first 4 CPUs 0-3.  My guess is this is a job for grep, sed, cut, or awk but I am not experienced enough to know which is the best utility(s) to use for the job.

```
#!/bin/bash

for cpuIndex in {0..3}
do
   # Get percent idle from line of specified  cpuIndex
   cpuPercentIdle= # How to get a desired line and space separated field number?
   # Can you do math in a bash script ?
   cpuPercentUsed=$((100 - $cpuPercentId))
   echo "CPU $cpuIndex : Idle=$cpuPercentIdle, Used=$cpuPercentUsed"
   done
done
```

Script Output:

```
CPU 0 : Idle=45.18, Used=54.82
CPU 1 : Idle=96.33, Used=3.67
CPU 2 : Idle=95.65, Used=4.35
CPU 3 : Idle=72.09, Used=27.91
```

**File:mpstat-log.txt**

```
Average:     CPU   %user   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal   %idle    intr/s
Average:     all   10.95    0.00    0.42    0.00    0.04    0.25    0.00   88.34   1586.71
Average:       0   51.50    0.00    3.32    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   45.18      0.00
Average:       1    3.67    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   96.33      2.66
Average:       2    4.35    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   95.65      0.00
Average:       3   27.57    0.00    0.33    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   72.09    997.34
Average:       4    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00     10.96
Average:       5    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
Average:       6    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00      0.00
Average:       7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    1.67    0.00   98.33    575.75
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance and tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '$2~/^[0-3]$/ {printf "CPU %d : Idle=%.2f, Used=%.2f\n",$2,$10,100-$10}' mpstat-log.txt
CPU 0 : Idle=45.18, Used=54.82
CPU 1 : Idle=96.33, Used=3.67
CPU 2 : Idle=95.65, Used=4.35
CPU 3 : Idle=72.09, Used=27.91
```

Comment: If there are > 10 CPUs, the regex `/[0-3]/` will match too many

Comment: @glenn good point. Updated answer to cover more cases. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just about all the tools you mention can do the job one way or another. Here's one with awk...

`awk '{ if ( $2 <= 3 ) print $10; }' mpstat-log.txt`

Comment: The more awk-ish way to write this is: `awk '$2 <= 3 {print $10}'`

Answer (score 2):

Solution using awk:

```
{ if($2 ~ /[0-3]/) {
    print $10
  }
}
```

gives:

```
$ awk -f t.awk input
45.18
96.33
95.65
72.09
```

In pure bash, something like this perhaps:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -a ARRAY
do
    if [[ "${ARRAY[1]}" =~ [0-3] ]]; then
        echo ${ARRAY[9]}
    fi
done < input
```

gives:

```
45.18
96.33
95.65
72.09
```

Bash cannot to floating point arithmetic, for that you can use `bc`. See this [link](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/mathc.html) for how you can use `bc` to do the math for you.

Comment: If there are > 10 CPUs, the regex `/[0-3]/` will match too many

Comment: @glenn jackman - true, limit it to a single digit using `/^[0-3]$/` instead.

Comment: Thank you all!
The stuff that is possible to cobble together with grep, awk, sed, etc. makes my head spin.  While very powerful, I feel sorry for the next Linux newbie that comes along to try and maintain.  I guess I just need to leave descriptive comments.